# bootstrap: how to delete padding from col-lg?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this structure:

```
    <div class="container" id="gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#" alt="car1">
        </div> <!-- /.col-lg-3, /.col-md-7 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#" alt="car1">
        </div> <!-- /.col-lg-3, /.col-md-7 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#" alt="car1">
        </div> <!-- /.col-lg-3, /.col-md-7 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#" alt="car1">
        </div> <!-- /.col-lg-3, /.col-md-7 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

And everything is ok - images are centered, resized. But there is one problem. I have a big padding? from left and right. It's looks like:

[image: problem with padding]

When I change "col-lg-3" to "col-lg-2" this padding is smaller, but... I dont want 6 pictures in one line. So - what I can do? I tired something like that, but there is no change:

```
.row-no-padding {
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be on the margin in col-lg or on the padding in img!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems  to be on the margin, not the padding. Can you change that and see if it works?

Comment: The problem is that col-lg-3 (with i used 4 times) divide my site by 4 - so every image gets 25% width of site(100%/4=25%). In this 25% the pictures takes up 15% of the page, not 25%, so this 10% is the orange area.

Comment: I know, but (I don't usually use bootstrap, so I might be wrong) I'd assume if you set de `margin` to `0`, that space would be gone.

Comment: I tired change margin and/or pading in .col-lg-3, .img-responsive, .center-block and always i have this orange area. I've been already working on this second hour :/

Comment: What if you change the width of `.row` or `.container`/`#gallery`?

Comment: This is amazing idea! :) I must take care of "mobile friendly" this concept and everything will be fine. Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

add new class (test) in img   and put in content

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block test" src="#" alt="car1">

   .test{
      width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem will disappear because we extend the image over the entire width of. I want to have a size such as now, but without this orange area (photos will be closer)

Comment: try use 
    <body>
    <div class="container">

your code
   </div>
   </body>

Answer (score 0):

The space is because of `col-lg-3`. It is dividing the screen`(12 column grids)` in `(4 column grid)` of equal size and your image is of small size than `4 col grid`. that's why it is showing padding to overcome the space left after image to cover the column.

Comment: I wrote exactly the same in comment (https://goo.gl/snDB9X). But I dont want this padding. The pictures must be in the middle of the page, but closer than now.

Comment: set img to width 100%.